# Different Order Id for order from multiple restaurants

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to place an order from multiple restaurants. When I place an order, same **Order ID** is adding in the database for orders. What I would like to have is, When the user places an order from multiple restaurants, I would like to have separate **Order ID** for them.

Here is my code:

```
$order_id = $this->generateNewOrderId();    
foreach ($cart_content->rest_item_list as $item) 
    {
        $td_data['order_id'] = $order_id;
        $td_data['item_id'] = $item->id;
        $i_details = $this->restaurant_menu_items_model->get_item_detail_by_id($item->id);
        $td_data['item_name'] = $i_details->name;
        $td_data['item_price'] = $i_details->price;
        $td_data['item_quantity'] = $item->quantity;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this stands to reason, since you're generating an order ID only once, outside the loop, not once per order. Just move it inside the loop:

```
foreach ($cart_content->rest_item_list as $item) {
    $order_id = $this->generateNewOrderId();
    $td_data['order_id'] = $order_id;
    //... etc ...
```